# How to check that a thread is complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having a lot of trouble with this. Consider this example:

```
public class Test {
    Thread t;

    public Test() {
        t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
    }

    public void Start() {
        t.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadFunction() {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Function Complete");
    }    
}


public static class Main {
    public Main() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Start();

        // sleep longer than my worker so it finishes
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // a place to place a breakpoint
        bool breakPointHere = true;
    }        
}
```

Now, I see the output of the console.log, but when I inspect Test's thread object, I see that IsAlive is still true, and ThreadStatus = TheadStatus.Running. Why is this? I wish to detect that the thread is truly complete, but I am confused as to how it can still be considered running if ThreadFunction() completes?

**EDIT 2:**

I finally tracked down the cause, Updating the code, and am going to answer my own question

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public abstract class Worker {
        protected bool shutdown;
        protected Thread t;

        private bool _isStopped = true;
        public bool IsStopped {
            get {
                return t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped;
            }
        }

        private bool _isPaused = false;
        public bool IsPaused {
            get {
                return _isPaused;
            }
        }

        private string stringRepresentation;

        public Worker() {
            t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
            stringRepresentation = "Thread id:" + t.ManagedThreadId;
            t.Name = stringRepresentation;
        }


        public void Start() {
            OnBeforeThreadStart();
            t.Start();
        }

        public void ScheduleStop() {
            shutdown = true;
        }

        public void SchedulePause() {
            OnPauseRequest();
            _isPaused = true;
        }

        public void Unpause() {
            _isPaused = false;
        }

        public void ForceStop() {
            t.Abort();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The main thread loop.
        /// </summary>
        private void ThreadFunction() {
            OnThreadStart();
            while (!shutdown) {
                if (!IsPaused) {
                    if (!OnLoop()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            OnShutdown();
        }

        public abstract void OnBeforeThreadStart();
        public abstract void OnThreadStart();
        public abstract bool OnLoop();
        public abstract void OnShutdown();
        public abstract void OnPauseRequest();


        public override string ToString() {
            return stringRepresentation;
        }
    }


    public class Test : Worker {
        public override void OnBeforeThreadStart() {
            Log.WriteLine(this + ": Thread about to be started...");
        }

        public override void OnThreadStart() {
            Log.WriteLine(this + ": Thread Started!");
        }

        public override bool OnLoop() {
            Log.WriteLine(this + ": I am doing the things...");
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnShutdown() {
            Log.WriteLine(this + ": Shutting down!");
        }

        public override void OnPauseRequest() {            
        }
    }



public static class Log {
    public delegate void LogDelegate(string text, string eventTime, Severity severity);

    public static event LogDelegate OnWriteLine;

    private static Queue<string> _pendingFileWrites = new Queue<string>();


    public enum Severity {
        Info,
        Warning,
        Error
    }


    public static void WriteLine(object line, Severity severity = Severity.Info) {
        string eventTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        string formatted = "[" + eventTime + "]: " + line;
        Console.WriteLine(formatted);

        lock (_pendingFileWrites) {
            _pendingFileWrites.Enqueue(formatted);
        }

        if (OnWriteLine != null) {
            // this is the offending line:
            OnWriteLine.Invoke((string)line, eventTime, severity);
        }
    }


    public static void WriteToFile(string path) {
        lock(_pendingFileWrites) {
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path);        
            while(_pendingFileWrites.Count > 0) {
                sw.WriteLine(
                    _pendingFileWrites.Dequeue()
                );
            }
            sw.Close();
        }   
    }
}



    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Test test = new Test();
                test.Start();
                tests.Add(test);
            }

            // sleep a little bit so they do the things
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            foreach (Test test in tests) {
                test.ScheduleStop();
            }

            bool allStopped;
            do {
                allStopped = true;
                foreach (Test test in tests) {
                    if (!test.IsStopped) {
                        allStopped = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (!allStopped);

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            // a place to place a breakpoint
            bool breakPointHere = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct thread? Do a `t.Name = "TestThread";` before you do `t.Start()` to help you uniquely identify the thread. Also, it is not that frequent to work directly with the `Thread` class in modern C#, in modern C# you usually work with the `Task` abstraction that wraps it. Lastly, where do you get `Console.Log(` from, the `Log` method is not part of the built in `System.Console` class.

Comment: This is a very trimmed down example, but in my real world use care there is only this one thread (in addition to the main thread), so I know for certain it is the correct thread I am looking at. I wasn't aware of the Task  abstraction though. I'll check that out, but I still want to understand this better

Comment: Also Console.Log doens;t exist. I was mixing up my .Net and Unity C# when I pumped out that example :P. It's a Console.WriteLine()

Comment: Please update your question to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

I think your original testing that lead you to believe `.IsAlive` would be true had some flaw in it, I tweaked your program in your question to the following to make it compile and to be able to see which thread it created.

```
public class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        Thread t;

        public Test()
        {
            t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
            t.Name = "TestThread";
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            t.Start();
        }

        private void ThreadFunction()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Function Complete");
        }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Start();

        // sleep longer than my worker so it finishes
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // a place to place a breakpoint
        bool breakPointHere = true;
    }
}
```

here is a screenshot of the running threads from inside ThreadFunction

[image]

Here is a screenshot from the end of the program

[image]

Notice that there is no "TestThread" thread.

Here is a screenshot from the locals window

[image]

`IsAlive` is false.

Comment: You are right; my testing method is absolutely flawed. I did essentially the same thing you did after reading your comment, and I got the same result. For some reason in my real world use scenario, my thread does not complete after the thread function returns. I'm trying to think about how I can make a minimal example that reproduces this...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to sleep to wait for your thread to finish?
If you don't, a better and more robust solution would be using [`Thread.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static class Main {
    public Main() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Start();

        test.Join(); // Waits for test to complete
        bool breakPointHere = true;
    }        
}
```

Comment: And it's even possible to create a timer, so it won't block forever... If you use a timeout of 0, you get a test method to test if it's still running. I don't think it's usefull to add similair answers, thats why  +1.

Comment: This isn't really the point of the question, I appreciate the feedback, but this is out of scope. I tried to make a very simple example is all. In real world use it is not like this. The example is bad, and I am trying to formulate one that demos the real problem I have. I thought I just wasn't understanding those properties, but apparently have a real bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that my issue was that my logging method was calling a UI thread function like so:

```
private void LogToForm(object line, string eventTime, Log.Severity severity) {
            if (dataGridView_LogInfo.InvokeRequired) {
                dataGridView_LogInfo.Invoke (
                    new Action<object, string, Log.Severity>(LogtoFormCallback), 
                    new object[] { line, eventTime, severity }
                );

            } else {
                LogtoFormCallback(line, eventTime, severity);
            }
        }
```

At the Invoke() line, the thread would hang forever. The solution was to replace it with BeginInvoke() instead.

EDIT: Also, my example was/is quite poor for this. I thought I didn't understand threads at a fundamental level, and that my examples would have been enough. Hopefully someone googles this though and has this same cause, and can try this solution.